# 3 layouts - middle is flexible

Tags: android, android-layout

I need the following thing:

3 layouts:

1. Header
2. Content
3. Footer

Header must be on the top footer must be sticked to the bottom (`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`).

But **how to make middle to occupy the whole other screen?** Thanks.

Comment: layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: no, in such case the middle one will be displayed over the footer layout.

Comment: Yes. The exact meaning of "fill_parent" depends on the container class, but in most cases it's taken to mean "grab up all the remaining space". In this case, Lopez has the right answer below, which is to use **android:layout_weight** to cause a view to be given all of the excess space at layout time.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution (with android:layout_weight and ScrollView):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="3" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Content"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Footer"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

And the result picture :

[image]

Comment: but what if I want header and footer to be some specific size and the content - the whole left space?

Comment: Is it possible to have a plan in your question? And then I change my answer.

Comment: @Volodymyr ScrollView might be useful if you use in content layout in case of content overflow from screen

Comment: This is a correct solution, but it's overkill. You have vertical linear layouts nested inside vertical linear layouts. You don't normally need to do that (unless you're doing clever things with borders or such.) You could have simply had a single linear layout with three textviews inside, assigning a layout_weight to the middle one.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Use the following lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_above="@+id/linearfooter"
       android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearfooter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Button" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="footer" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

hope this helps you. [image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a height of 0dp and

```
android:layout_weight
```

set to 1

Comment: it has to be a LinearLayout

Comment: In this case, you won't need to set the height to 0dp, and yes, this works fine as a child of a linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've got the next solution:

To the middle layout I added:

```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_above="@id/footer"
      android:layout_below="@id/header"
      android:layout_weight="1">
```

And it works!